# Html control properties order in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, properties

i am seeing some weird things with respect to IE browser..
I have html control and have some properties..I want the order of the property to be same in chrome and IE...Looks like IE is rendering this control with difference properties order.

```
<input name="UserName" id="UserName" type="text" value="xyz" maxlength="120" tabindex="1"/>
```

IE rendered textbox-

```
<input name="UserName" tabindex="1" id="UserName" type="text" maxlength="120" value="xyz>
```

Chrome is showing exactly the same order which was placed.

```
<input name="UserName" id="UserName" type="text" value="xyz" maxlength="120" tabindex="1">
```

Can anyone please let me know how to make IE control properties sequence same as it placed.

Thanks,
Roshan

Comment: Why does the ordering matter? There should be no difference between the two when the control is rendered.

Comment: some validation has to be displayed based on control property.e.g.i have textbox on which i need to do 3 validation 1.required field 2. length 3.some special character...what i did, i created three json property and values are regex expression..i am dynamically rendering this control along with these three property ..while assigning these properties to control i am adding them as per required sequence..and like i said required field should have first priority to execute and all other subsequent properties..other thing these properties are dynamic at compile time i may not know its property

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Sun is right - the browser will choose its own order.

It makes no difference at all as long as all the attributes are present - you can still retrieve them with getAttribute.

Comment: some validation has to be displayed based on control property.e.g.i have textbox on which i need to do 3 validation 1.required field 2. length 3.some special character...what i did, i created three json property and values are regex expression..i am dynamically rendering this control along with these three property ..while assigning these properties to control i am adding them as per required sequence..and like i said required field should have first priority to execute and all other subsequent properties..other thing these properties are dynamic at compile time i may not know its property.

Comment: Not clear I understand fully, but if you need to validate the text in the input box then you need to validate the input value. The attributes of the control don't change when you enter data. Why your three validations require json and regex is unclear to me.

Comment: this is my textbox control <input autocomplete="off" class="global-fluid-input has-error tooltip-block" id="UserName" maxlength="120" minlength="0" name="UserName" nospaces placeholder="" required-field tabindex="1" textlen5to120 type="text" value="" data-tooltip="0"> here i have three properties nospaces,required-field & textlen5to120.all these properties nothing bt json key &its values nothing but regex.i hav to validate required-field first and then textlen5to120.if i get any validation error for required-field then i will nt go ahead & check textlen5to120 at a time only 1 tooltip im showin

Comment: continuation...basically based on control properties i am deciding which error message to show and all those properties are dynamic custom from json file.Am i clear now?

Comment: I still say you need to be checking the Value of Input control once text is entered (getDocumentById("UserName").value). If it's a blank string then 'required field- enter value', if string.length <5 or >120 then 'out of range', if string.indexOf(" ")!=-1 then 'includes space'. But the order of the attributes/properties of the control in the browser still make no difference.

Comment: ** Correction to above:  document.getElementById...  (sorry)